# Как кастомизировать регистрацию в битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите как кастомизировать страницу регистрации в bitrix?

Comment: Скопируйте шаблоны из компонентов `bitrix/components/bitrix/system.auth.*` в свою тему и там уже кастомизируйте

Comment: @DmitryKozlov так и сделал, но ничего не работает. подскажите пожалуйста может быть где-то нужно прописать пути к шаблону?

Comment: скопировали в `local/templates/{имя-шаблона}/components/bitrix` ?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov спасибо разобрался